# How can i install the package Microsoft.Data.SqlClient in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to install the package Microsoft.Data.SqlClient  , I have tried the following

```
 Install-Package Microsoft.Data.SqlClient
```

but get an error:

Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and package name 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient'

How can i install this package ?

UPDATE:

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection 
$conn.ConnectionString = 
     "Server=testdb.database.windows.net;Authentication=Active 
      Directory Default;Encrypt=True;Database=testdb1;"
$conn.AccessToken = $(az account get-access-token --subscription 
    "TestSubscription" --resource https://database.windows.net -- 
     query accessToken -o tsv)
```

ERROR:

```
 Exception Message: Exception setting "ConnectionString": "Invalid 
 value for key 'authentication'."
```

Comment: The Microsoft.Data.SqlClient library is distributed as a NuGet package. Add a NuGet reference to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient. -- source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/download-microsoft-sqlclient-data-provider?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: so i assume i must install it on the pc ?

Comment: i am using    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ConnectionString $connectString -Query $str -OutputSqlErrors $true  to try and connect and the connectionstring has Authentication=Active Directory Default which is Microsoft.Dat.Sqlclient ?

Comment: You do not need to install.  Add to top of module : using assembly System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: I have updated  the question and put the code i use in powershell with the error